# How to get all the Questions & Answers from a QnA Maker V4.0 using Single API?

Tags: c#, botframework, chatbot, azure-language-understanding, azure-qna-maker

Is there any API for getting all the Questions & Answers that I have created in QnA Maker V4. Currently I am able to see there is an api that will return the appropriate answer based on the question that I have raised.

I have verified the following microsoft documents and unable to find the proper API.

**End point for getting answer based on the proper question :**

> https://{QnA-Maker-endpoint}/knowledgebases/{knowledge-base-ID}/generateAnswer

**QNA Maker API document :**

> https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5a93fcf85b4ccd136866eb37/operations/5ac266295b4ccd1554da75ff

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get all questions by downloading the knowledgebase. Use this API:
https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5a93fcf85b4ccd136866eb37/operations/knowledgebases_download

You can test [here](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5a93fcf85b4ccd136866eb37/operations/knowledgebases_download/console), but make sure you use the key from your Azure QnA resource and not the `Authorization: EndpointKey` from the QnA portal.

Comment: Already know this link but I thought the download doing something different functionality. Thanks !!