# Is it Possible to Query QnAMaker using URL Parameters?

Tags: javascript, html, botframework, azure-qna-maker

I'm not sure is this is possible. I need to query QnAMaker for answers using a URL Parameter and return the result on the Virtual Assistant chat window (e.g. https://BotFrameWorkURL.html?searchTerm=Password%20Reset.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get all the Questions & Answers from a QnA Maker V4.0 using Single API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59862348/how-to-get-all-the-questions-answers-from-a-qna-maker-v4-0-using-single-api)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly...if you're asking if you could use *only* the URL parameter and no request, body, then the answer would be "no". The API expects a POST request and to receive a payload body that contains *at least* the `"question"`

See QnA Maker documentation on the `generate answer` API [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/how-to/metadata-generateanswer-usage#generateanswer-request-configuration).

**URL Format**: `https://{QnA-Maker-endpoint}/knowledgebases/{knowledge-base-ID}/generateAnswer`

**JSON body example**:

1. Simplest:

```
{
    "question": "How much wood would a woodchuck chuk?"
}
```

2. With more QnA Options:

```
{
    "question": "qna maker and luis",
    "top": 6,
    "isTest": true,
    "scoreThreshold": 30,
    "rankerType": "" // values: QuestionOnly
    "strictFilters": [
    {
        "name": "category",
        "value": "api"
    }],
    "userId": "sd53lsY="
}
```